# What are the entries in the 2x2 $W$ gate used for walking along the welded-trees graph of Childs et al.?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, linear-algebra, quantum-walks

As an extension of a famous description of non-local Hamiltonian simulation in section 4.7.3 of Nielsen and Chuang, the welded-trees [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209131) of Childs, *et al.* provides the following circuit for use in the quantum walk along their graph:

[image: Circuit in Childs et al.]

Here, $a$ and $b$ are two different $2n$-bit labels for the nodes of the graph, while $W$ appears somehow related to a SWAP gate used in the traversal of the graph.

In particular, the eigenvalues of SWAP are $\pm 1$ because SWAP$\ne$SWAP$^2=\mathbb 1$, while the unique eigenvector of the SWAP gate having eigenvalue $-1$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|01\rangle-|10\rangle)$.

Childs *et al.* define $W$ as:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
W|00\rangle=|00\rangle\\
W\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)=|01\rangle\\
W\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|01\rangle-|10\rangle)=|10\rangle\\
W|11\rangle=|11\rangle
\end{eqnarray}$$

**But what, then, are the entries of this gate $W$?**

Are they something like:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\pi q/2}\cos\frac{\pi q}{2} & -ie^{i\pi q/2}\sin\frac{\pi q}{2} & \: 0 \ \\
0 & -ie^{i\pi q/2}\sin\frac{\pi q}{2} & e^{i\pi q/2}\cos \frac{\pi q}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

for some $q$?

I'm really just trying to understand that paper in general, and this circuit in particular, in more detail.  Childs *et al.* trotterizes this circuit over all the different edge-colorings of the graph to do the Hamiltonian simulation thereof; after about a linear amount of time there's a decent odds that the particle, which was initially at node $|\psi\rangle=$ ENTRY, has found the EXIT.

Comment: You can get $W|01\rangle$ by summing the second and third equation and dividing by $\sqrt{2}$ and $W|10\rangle$ by taking the difference between the second equation and the third one and then once again dividing by $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition you gave,
$$
W=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
$$
(Just think of the central $2\times 2$ block like a Hadamard, which would convert $|+\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$ except that, in this case, the basis elements are $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ instead of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$.)

Comment: Awesome! Do you know why the circuit shows that the $|10\rangle$ output controls the CCNOT parity count of the bottom ancilla?

Comment: $T$ is basically the SWAP operator in parallel. Note that $S=I-2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ where $|\psi\rangle=(|01\rangle-|10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}=W^\dagger|10\rangle$. This means that $e^{iSt}=e^{iSt}$ effectively adds a relative phase to the component in $|\psi\rangle$ compared to everything else. So, the idea is that $W$ converts the singlet state into $|10\rangle$. Then controlled off those qubits being $|10\rangle$, it adds a phase.

Comment: Oh I see! That's awesome! The H'nian in § 4.7.3 of Mike and Ike is a tensor product of $Z$ gates, where the unique eigenvector having an eigenvalue of $-1$ is $|1\rangle$ - this is why their circuit uses CNOT gates with a filled-in bubble to count the parity. But, the H'nian in Childs et al. is a tensor product of a bunch of SWAP gates, and the singlet state is the one having an eigenvalue of $-1$ - *this* maps to $|10\rangle$.  Hence the circuit in Childs et al. has a CCNOT with a filled-in bubble for the first qubit and an open bubble for the second. How neat is that!